# How to get escaped hex value unescaped in Python

Tags: python, file-io, type-conversion

I implemented a simple file seek and read in [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29):

```
>>>f = open("<filepath>", "rb")
>>>f.seek(0x20) #offset 0x20
>>>byte=f.read(4) #4 byte space
```

I ended up with

```
>>>byte
'\xe0\x00\x00\x00'
```

which is the expected result, but I need to use it as a hex value without escapes for further calculations.

How can I convert such a string into an unescaped hex value? (In the above example '\xe0\x00\x00\x00' should tranform into 'e0000000' or '0xe0000000'.)

Answer (score 1):

Use `encode('hex')`:

```
>>> byte.encode('hex')
'e0000000'

# convert it to int
>>> int(byte.encode('hex'), 16)
3758096384
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use byte.encode('hex') to get the hex value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `struct` module to unpack the bytes into a number and then format that the way you wish.

```
inport struct
print '{:08x}'.format(struct.unpack('>I', byte)[0])
```

Output:

```
e0000000
```